# Proving polynomial limit theorems

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

I am pretty confused on this math question. It is a two-parter but I'm not sure what part a is asking me, perhaps someone on StackExchange could help.

The question reads as follows:

**(a) If p is a polynomial, prove, using limit theorems, that**

$$\lim_{x\to a}p\left(x\right) = p\left(a\right)$$

**(b) Use the result in (a) to evaluate**
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(x^3 – 8x^2 + 2x – 1\right)$$

Could somebody give me some hints about 'proving' part a with limit theorems? I was under the impression that it was a limit theorem. Because I have a polynomial wouldn't I just replace the value of $x$ with $a$? What else can I say about it? And wouldn't I just replace $x$ with $0$ in part b?

Comment: The immediate way I see to do this is not the simple way, but to use delta-epsilon proofs on the polynomial a*x and then use induction for higher order polyonmials. Maybe I'm the only one who isn't clear what you mean, but what do you mean by limit theorems? Like the squeeze/sandwich theorem?

Comment: I assume limit theorems, the question is pretty ambiguous it seems.

Comment: But there are plenty of theorems about limits. Like the one cited below by Sami Ben Romdhane. And that theorem basically is the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: You need to use induction on degree of $p(x)$.

**Update**: It is a bit surprising that this was a relatively easy question on the topic of "limits" but still no good answers. I therefore expand my hint into a complete answer.

We use induction of the degree of $p(x)$. To begin induction we first prove that the result is true for polynomials of degree $0$ and degree $1$. In this process we will use the following two standard limit theorems:

1) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}\{f(x) + g(x)\} = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) + \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

2) $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}\{f(x) \cdot g(x)\} = \lim_{x \to a}f(x) \cdot \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$

Let us first start with polynomials of degree $0$. In this case $p(x)$ is just a constant $k$. We have thus $p(x) = k$ for all $x$ and hence in particular $p(a) = k$. Now we need to show that $\lim_{x \to a}p(x) = p(a)$ or $\lim_{x \to a}k = k$. This is simple enough as we see that variable $x$ is not involved and thus limit of $k$ remains $k$ (this argument is informal and a proper proof is based on $\epsilon, \delta$ type argument. In fact in this case it is simple as we have $|f(x) - L| = |k - k| = 0$ which is always less than $\epsilon$ whatever $\delta$ we choose.)

Next we handle polynomials of degree $1$. Let $p(x) = Ax + B$. Then we have $p(a) = Aa + B$. We have $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x \to a}p(x) &= \lim_{x \to a}Ax + B\\
&= \lim_{x \to a}A \cdot\lim_{x \to a}x + \lim_{x \to a}B\text{ (using limit rules }(1)\text{ and }(2))\\
&= A \lim_{x \to a}x + B\\
&= Aa + B = p(a)\end{aligned}$$ The last line uses the simple result that $\lim_{x \to a}x = a$ (again a formal proof requires that for every $\epsilon > 0$ we find a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x - a| < \delta$ where $f(x) = x$ and $L = a$. In this case $|f(x) - L| = |x - a|$ so that $\delta = \epsilon$ will do the job.)

Now we assume that the result holds for any polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ so that if $p(x)$ is any polynomial of degree $n$ then $\lim_{x \to a}p(x) = p(a)$. Let us now try to see what we get if $p(x)$ is of degree $(n + 1)$. Clearly if $p(x)$ is of degree $(n + 1)$ we can write $$\begin{aligned}p(x) &= a_{0}x^{n + 1} + a_{1}x^{n} + \cdots + a_{n}x + a_{n + 1}\\
&= x\left(a_{0}x^{n} + a_{1}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + a_{n}\right) + a_{n + 1}\\
&= x\cdot q(x) + k\end{aligned}$$ where $q(x)$ is polynomial of degree $n$ and $k$ is some constant $k = a_{n + 1}$.

We then see that $p(a) = a\cdot q(a) + k$. We can now proceed in following manner $$\begin{aligned}\lim_{x \to a}p(x) &= \lim_{x \to a}\{x\cdot q(x) + k\}\\
&= \lim_{x \to a}x\cdot\lim_{x \to a}q(x) + \lim_{x \to a}k\text{ (using rules }(1) \text{ and }(2))\\
&= a\cdot q(a) + k\text{ (result holds for polynomial }q(x)\text{ of degree }n)\\
&= p(a)\end{aligned}$$ The proof by induction is now complete.

Note that the answer provided by Sami Ben Romdhane is a "technically correct statement" but it does not offer an answer to the current question from OP. What he mentions needs to be supported by a proof that polynomials are continuous and this itself is almost similar to the inductive proof I gave above (there are non-inductive proofs also, but they need some more algebra than the inductive proof I gave above).

Answer (score 4):

Since any polynomial $p$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$ then we have
$$\lim_{x\to a}p(x)=p(a)$$
so to find the limit just evaluate the polynomial on $a$.

Comment: This somewhat begs the question: how do you _prove_ that polynomials are continuous on $\mathbb{R}$?  I'm presuming that that hasn't been covered yet, and in fact that appears to be exactly what's being asked to be proved.

Comment: The limit theorems are the results on the operations of the limits: sum and subtraction of limits, multiplication of the limit by a constant...

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: I believe that your answer should address the concern raised by Steven Stadnicki. You need to show that polynomials are continuous or need to answer the question here without mentioning anything about continuity. Its a relatively easy task which I have done via induction in my answer.