# Show that $\lim_{x \to a}{P(x)} = P(a)$ for any polynomial $P(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, solution-verification, continuity

In my calculus textbook I was given the following

**Problem:** If $P(x)$ is a polynomial, show that $\lim_{x \to a}{P(x)} = P(a)$.

I found the following solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838900/proving-polynomial-limit-theorems), were a proof was given using induction. In my textbook, the problem was given in an chapter regarding limit laws, a precise definition is only given later in the following chapter and inductions weren't used up until then. So I decided to try solve this problem using only the limit laws. In that, I am taking these for granted without proving them.

**Solution:** Per definition we have a polynomial $P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n k_i x^i$ were each $k_i$ is a constant and $k, x \in \Bbb{R}$. Thus $P(a) = \sum_{i=0}^n k_i a^i$.

Now, using the limit laws for sum, multiplication and power we can write

$$
\lim_{x \to a}{P(x)}
 = \lim_{x \to a}{\sum_{i=0}^n k_i x^i}
 = \sum_{i=0}^n{\lim_{x \to a}k_i \cdot \left(\lim_{x \to a}x\right)^i}
 = \sum_{i=0}^n{k_i \cdot \left(\lim_{x \to a}x\right)^i}$$

and since $\lim_{x \to a}x = a$ we get

$$
\lim_{x \to a}{P(x)}
 = \sum_{i=0}^n{k_i \cdot \left(\lim_{x \to a}x\right)^i}
 = \sum_{i=0}^n{k_i a^i}
 = P(a)
$$

$\blacksquare$

Is my reasoning correct? I am not sure, if I can use these manipulations on the sum without using induction. Thanks in advance for any comments and answers.

Comment: All is correct. However at the start you say "where $k$ is a constant. You mean to say "each $k_i$ is a constant,..".

Comment: This is OK, assuming that you already have limit laws $\lim_{x \to a}\sum_{i=0}^n f_i(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n \lim_{x \to a}f_i(x)$, etc., although as the answer below indicates you should mention that all the limits on the right exist first.  Also note that you are implicitly using induction here, since an identity like the one I mention is proved using induction.

Comment: Thx @coffeemath, I corrected this.

Answer (score -1):

It is essentially the correct argument but personally I dislike it when these arguments are written in this way. I have typically found my point of view to be unpopular but I still try to emphasize it when I teach this stuff; let me try to explain...

Basically my issue is that in the chain of equalities, some of the earlier equalities are only justified by parts of the argument that come later. When you split the limit of a product as the product of the limits, this is only justified by the fact that both limits exist. But the fact that both limits exist is something you explain afterwards (or barely at all)!

Honestly, this is a really bad way to write down mathematics. It's one of those things that's only OK because you already know the answer i.e. it's an exercise that says "Show that....", but when you're trying to actually *use* mathematical rigour for real in order to find something out that you don't already know, this is the kind of thing that leads to confusion and mistakes.

Comment: If they're allowed to assume that both limits exist (i.e. if they are allowed to assume certain limit laws that they proved in class), then I don't see much of an issue with the proof.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it would be an unpopular answer! But to try to address the comment: The 'proof' is some blend of the logical content of the argument and the way it is written down. Viewed purely through the lens of the former, it is not incorrect in any way. But learning to write proofs ought to be as much about the latter as the former. It's not enough to write down a series of equalities that are true in a literal sense, you need to actually *make* a correct *argument* as you do so. And there's more to that, for example like using proper sentences to explain the steps, in the right order.